# Como eu consigo criar um retângulo com Java Script

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Eu estou tentando criar um retângulo usando Javascript, evitando usar as funções do canvas como moveto and drawto. Porém meu retângulo não fica bem. Segue o código:

```
function retangulo(x1, y1, x2, y2){
            let horizontalx = x2 - x1;
            let verticaly = y2 - y1;
            linhaVertical(x1, y1, verticaly);
            linhaHorizontal(x1, y1, horizontalx);
            linhaVertical(x2, y2, verticaly);
            linhaHorizontal(x2, y2, horizontalx);

        }
function linhaVertical(x,y, size) {
            for(let i=0; i < size; i++) {
                acender(x, y + i);
            }
        }
function linhaHorizontal(x,y, size) {
            for(let i=0; i < size; i++) {
                acender(x + i, y);
            }
        }
function acender(x, y) {
            let index = (x + y * width) * 4;
            imageData.data[ index ] = 0;
            imageData.data[ index + 1] = 0;
            imageData.data [ index + 2] =0;
            imageData.data[ index + 3 ] = 255;
        }
```

Agradeço a atenção em antecipação

Comment: Coloca o erro, ou captura de tela do problema. E outra não use "let" pois ele só é compatível em alguns navegadores, use sempre "var".

Comment: @Sveen O suporte de `let` ronda os 91% dos usuarios mundais, incluindo o famoso IE, [veja aqui](https://caniuse.com/#feat=let). Todos os navegadores suportam, ainda que alguns só a partir de determinada versão, por isso não vejo problema no uso de `let` a menos que precise especificamente de suportar versões antigas de navegadores.

Answer (score 0):

Tens que trocar os pontos na 3ª e 4ª linha.

```
linhaVertical(x1, y1, verticaly);
linhaHorizontal(x1, y1, horizontalx);
linhaVertical(x2, y1, verticaly);
linhaHorizontal(x1, y2, horizontalx);
```

Answer (score 0):

Parece que o seu código está no caminho certo, mas você precisa ajustar algumas coisas para garantir que o retângulo seja desenhado corretamente.
Algumas sugestões:

Adicionar o objeto imageData: Você está usando um objeto chamado imageData, mas ele não está declarado ou inicializado no código que você compartilhou. Certifique de ter algo como:

```
let imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

antes de chamar a função retangulo.

Corrigir a função acender: Certifique-se que o width está definido corretamente. Se você estiver trabalhando com um canvas, você pode obter o width do canvas. Adicione algo como:

```
let width = canvas.width;
```

no início da sua função ou ajuste de acordo com sua lógica.

Com essas correções ficaria algo como:

```
let canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"); // substitua "myCanvas" pelo ID do seu canvas
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function retangulo(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    let horizontalx = x2 - x1;
    let verticaly = y2 - y1;
    linhaVertical(x1, y1, verticaly);
    linhaHorizontal(x1, y1, horizontalx);
    linhaVertical(x2, y2, verticaly);
    linhaHorizontal(x2, y2, horizontalx);
}

function linhaVertical(x, y, size) {
    for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        acender(x, y + i);
    }
}

function linhaHorizontal(x, y, size) {
    for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        acender(x + i, y);
    }
}

function acender(x, y) {
    let imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    let width = canvas.width;

    let index = (x + y * width) * 4;
    imageData.data[index] = 0;
    imageData.data[index + 1] = 0;
    imageData.data[index + 2] = 0;
    imageData.data[index + 3] = 255;

    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0); // atualize o canvas com os dados modificados
}
```

Lembre-se de substituir "myCanvas" pelo ID do seu canvas. Certifique-se de que o canvas já está no seu HTML antes de executar esse código.